# How to add new repository to Sonatype Nexus?

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin, sonatype

Actullay till today we were using default BuildConfig.groovy to download plugins but now we are looking to create a local repository we have Sonatype nexus.

1. Created grails simple application by sts 3.5.0  which by default download some plugins for example

   ```
   build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

   // plugins for the compile step
   compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
   compile ':cache:1.1.8'
   compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

   runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
   runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
   runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
   ```

For this I tried to create a new proxy repository in Sonatype nexus but, there are few fields I don't know like

Repository ID: grails_plugins

Repository Name: Grails Plugins

Repository Type: will take default

Provider : (this field I'm not getting options are maven1, maven2, npm, NuGet, Rubygems)

Format: will take default

Repository Policy: will take default

Default Local Storage Location : (this field I'm not getting)

Override Local Storage Location : (this field I'm not getting)

Remote Storage Location : (this field I'm not getting)

while creating new repository I am not getting few things which I have mentioned by **"(this field I'm not getting)"**.

please tell me what I need to give input to those field.

After that how can I use that particular thing to download plugins from local repository or maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to create two repository
1. mavenCentral
2. grailsCentral

1. For **mavenCentral** you give these inputs

   Repository ID: grails_plugins (your wish)

   Repository Name: Grails Plugins (your wish)

   Repository Type: will take default

   Provider : maven2

   Format: will take default

   Repository Policy: will take default

   Default Local Storage Location : blank

   Override Local Storage Location : blank

   Remote Storage Location :
   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
2. For **grailsCentral** you give these inputs

   Repository ID: grails_plugins1 (your wish)

   Repository Name: Grails Plugins1 (your wish)

   Repository Type: will take default

   Provider : maven2

   Format: will take default

   Repository Policy: will take default

   Default Local Storage Location : blank

   Override Local Storage Location : blank

   Remote Storage Location :
   https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/

And add below two lines in repository closure of BuildConfig.groovy

```
 repositories {
    // these links get created once you create repository
    mavenRepo "http://ip-address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/grails_plugins1/"
    mavenRepo "http://ip-address:8081/nexus/content/repositories/grails_plugins/"
}
```

**Optional** : I have commented following in same repository closure

```
    //grailsPlugins()
    //grailsHome()
    //mavenLocal()
    //grailsCentral()
    //mavenCentral()
```